# xml to array conversion

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have following xml which I am converting to array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <student-No>S0001</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>Doe1</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-000</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0002</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>Sheen</firstName>
  <lastName>D</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-001</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0003</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>Mark</firstName>
  <lastName>Webber</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-002</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0004</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>Eric</firstName>
  <lastName>smith</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-003</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0005</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>Larry</firstName>
  <lastName>Page</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-004</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0006</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>Mark</firstName>
  <lastName>z</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-005</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0007</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>william</firstName>
  <lastName>s</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-006</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0008</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>bill</firstName>
  <lastName>G</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-007</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0009</student-No>
  <Title>Mr</Title>
  <firstName>ricky</firstName>
  <lastName>p</lastName>
  <gender>male</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-008</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
  <student-No>S0010</student-No>
  <Title>Mrs</Title>
  <firstName>emma</firstName>
  <lastName>Webber</lastName>
  <gender>female</gender>
  <address>australia</address>
  <mobileNumber>987654321</mobileNumber>
  <homeNumber>000-000-009</homeNumber>
  <email>dummyemail@email.com</email>
  <institute>act</institute>
  <grade>begineer</grade>
</root>
```

I am using following code to generate xml

```
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r(@json_decode(@json_encode($xmlObject),1));
```

It is generating following output as array

```
Array ( [student-No] => Array ( [0] => S0001 [1] => S0002 [2] => S0003 [3] => S0004 [4] => S0005 [5] => S0006 [6] => S0007 [7] => S0008 [8] => S0009 [9] => S0010 ) [Title] => Array ( [0] => Mr [1] => Mr [2] => Mr [3] => Mr [4] => Mr [5] => Mr [6] => Mr [7] => Mr [8] => Mr [9] => Mrs ) [firstName] => Array ( [0] => John [1] => Sheen [2] => Mark [3] => Eric [4] => Larry [5] => Mark [6] => william [7] => bill [8] => ricky [9] => emma ) [lastName] => Array ( [0] => Doe1 [1] => D [2] => Webber [3] => smith [4] => Page [5] => z [6] => s [7] => G [8] => p [9] => Webber ) [gender] => Array ( [0] => male [1] => male [2] => male [3] => male [4] => male [5] => male [6] => male [7] => male [8] => male [9] => female ) [address] => Array ( [0] => australia [1] => australia [2] => australia [3] => australia [4] => australia [5] => australia [6] => australia [7] => australia [8] => australia [9] => australia ) [mobileNumber] => Array ( [0] => 987654321 [1] => 987654321 [2] => 987654321 [3] => 987654321 [4] => 987654321 [5] => 987654321 [6] => 987654321 [7] => 987654321 [8] => 987654321 [9] => 987654321 ) [homeNumber] => Array ( [0] => 000-000-000 [1] => 000-000-001 [2] => 000-000-002 [3] => 000-000-003 [4] => 000-000-004 [5] => 000-000-005 [6] => 000-000-006 [7] => 000-000-007 [8] => 000-000-008 [9] => 000-000-009 ) [email] => Array ( [0] => dummyemail@email.com [1] => dummyemail@email.com [2] => dummyemail@email.com [3] => dummyemail@email.com [4] => dummyemail@email.com [5] => dummyemail@email.com [6] => dummyemail@email.com [7] => dummyemail@email.com [8] => dummyemail@email.com [9] => dummyemail@email.com ) [institute] => Array ( [0] => act [1] => act [2] => act [3] => act [4] => act [5] => act [6] => act [7] => act [8] => act [9] => act ) [grade] => Array ( [0] => begineer [1] => begineer [2] => begineer [3] => begineer [4] => begineer [5] => begineer [6] => begineer [7] => begineer [8] => begineer [9] => begineer ) )
```

Here it has created all student-no elements as one array, all Title elements as one array
in resultant two dimensional array. 
Instead of this, I want output like this where each row is element of each array
for example

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [student-No] => S0001 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => John [lastName] => Doe1 [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-000 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [1] => Array ( [student-No] => S0002 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => Sheen [lastName] => D [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-001 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [2] => Array ( [student-No] => S0003 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => Mark [lastName] => Webber [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-002 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [3] => Array ( [student-No] => S0004 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => Eric [lastName] => smith [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-003 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [4] => Array ( [student-No] => S0005 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => Larry [lastName] => Page [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-004 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [5] => Array ( [student-No] => S0006 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => Mark [lastName] => z [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-005 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [6] => Array ( [student-No] => S0007 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => william [lastName] => s [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-006 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [7] => Array ( [student-No] => S0008 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => bill [lastName] => G [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-007 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [8] => Array ( [student-No] => S0009 [Title] => Mr [firstName] => ricky [lastName] => p [gender] => male [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-008 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) [9] => Array ( [student-No] => S0010 [Title] => Mrs [firstName] => emma [lastName] => Webber [gender] => female [address] => australia [mobileNumber] => 987654321 [homeNumber] => 000-000-009 [email] => dummyemail@email.com [institute] => act [grade] => begineer ) )
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Nothing as simplistic as converting your XML to JSON and then to an array is going to do the job here. I suggest looking into the DOMDocument APIs. Some pseudocode for an approach you can use is `$students = array(); $student = array(); foreach(element under root){ if(element name == "student-No") { $student = array(); $students[] = $student; } $student[element name] = element value; }`

Comment: @JLRishe Pretty much what I was about to suggest, and worthy of an answer rather than a comment, although SimpleXML is just as suitable as the DOM in this case. There are a couple of bugs in the algorithm as you wrote it there, too, e.g. you create a blank `$student` *before* you file the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that XML is not particularly well designed, and has no element grouping the properties of each student together. You will have to loop through all the child nodes in order (using [`->children()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)) and check their names as you go through (using [`->getName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php)), creating a new "student" each time you encounter a `<student-No>` node.

The rough algorithm might look like something like this:

```
# create an empty list of students

foreach ( $xml->children() as $node )
{
    if ( $node->getName() == 'student-No' )
    {
        # add completed student array to the list
        # (unless this is the first student)

        # create a new empty student array
    }

    # set $node->getName() in the current student array to (string)$node
}

# add the last completed student to the list
```

Comment: yes, I thought same that xml is also not correctly designed. I am getting xml from some different source, let me check if I can change this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it might work

```
<?php
      $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);                              
                                    $json = json_encode($xmlObject); 
                                    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
                                    //print_r($array);
            //Array in which all values are stored
                                    $jsonArray = array();
        //temporary arrays to store each array value
                                    $temp1 = array();
                                    $temp2 = array();
                                    $temp3 = array();
                                    foreach ($array as $values){
                                             array_push($temp1 , $values[0]);
                                             array_push($temp2 , $values[1]);
                                             array_push($temp3 , $values[2]);
                                    }
                                    $jsonArr = array($temp1 , $temp2 , $temp3);
                                    print_r($jsonArr);
                                    ?>
```

This outputs

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => S0001 [1] => Mr [2] => John [3] => Doe1 [4] => male [5] => australia [6] => 987654321 [7] => 000-000-000 [8] => dummyemail@email.com [9] => act [10] => begineer ) [1] => Array ( [0] => S0002 [1] => Mr [2] => Sheen [3] => D [4] => male [5] => australia [6] => 987654321 [7] => 000-000-001 [8] => dummyemail@email.com [9] => act [10] => begineer ) [2] => Array ( [0] => S0003 [1] => Mr [2] => Mark [3] => Webber [4] => male [5] => australia [6] => 987654321 [7] => 000-000-002 [8] => dummyemail@email.com [9] => act [10] => begineer ) )
```

Hence iam using three array variables iam getting value upto third array value. If you want more , you can create.